# Highcharts - Enable border for 1 column/bar only?

Tags: highcharts

I have a bar chart and I would like to color one of the series white and enable a black border for this series only.

I'd rather not enable a border for everything. Is this possible?

I have a fiddle example - I was hoping it could be achieved in a similar way to the 'color' attribute of the series, but I can't see anything in the API;

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Measure',
        data: [{
            y: 10}, { y:9, color: 'white'}, { y: 8 }, { y: 7 }, { y: 7.2 }]

    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZzXY2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that 'borderColor' is an acceptable attribute of each of the data points, it's just not documented.

Turn the border on and set the default color to white:

```
plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
             }
            }
```

Set the border color within the appropriate series

```
         series: [{
        name: 'Measure',
        data: [
            {y: score2, color: colors[1], borderColor:'Yellow'}, 
            {y: scoreprev, color: colors[4] },
            {y: score1, color: colors[0] },
            {y: score3, color: colors[2] },
            {y: score4, color: colors[3] }] }]
```

Comment: Some CSS attributes can be used. BTW, you can accept your own answer.